# Using jQuery plugin Tag-it...want to use myArray[i].tag rather than all in myArray, how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-plugins, tags

So, I am using the tag-it jquery plugin: http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/

They have the array being sent in as ['tag 1', 'tag 2', 'tag 3', etc.]

What I want to do is have it more of like below, where I am only looking for the tags, ie allAccounts[i].tag rather than allAccounts

```
var allAccounts = new Array();

function account(id, network, tag)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.network = network;
    this.tag = tag;
}

allAccounts.push(new account(
    123,
    'facebook',
    'my tag'
));
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

From the plugin:

```
if (this.options.availableTags || this.options.tagSource) {
    this._tagInput.autocomplete({
        source: this.options.tagSource,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            if (that._tagInput.val() === '') {
                that.removeTag(that._lastTag(), false);
            }
            that.createTag(ui.item.value);
            // Preventing the tag input to be updated with the chosen value.
            return false;
        }
    })
```

where availableTags = array being passed in

js source: http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/js/tag-it.js

Comment: I think I sorted it out for the most part:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data

Viewing the source code, can see how they do it... didn't work perfectly with the plugin, so had to tweak it.